# Laravel 5: Redirect "blog/{id}" to "blog/{slug}" - Trying to get property of non-object error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to redirect users that go to blog/{id} to blog/{slug} with the slug being the slug of the id they entered.

What I am doing is not working. I dd{$article->slug} and get the correct string, yet when I try to redirect I get "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

I'm using route/model binding. This is my RouteServiceProvider:

```
    $router->bind('blog', function($slug)
    {
        if ($slug) {
            if(is_numeric($slug)) {
                $article = Article::findOrFail($slug);

                return redirect('blog/' . $article->slug);
            }

            return Article::with('images')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        }
    });
```

This is my show method in controller:

```
public function show(Article $article)
{
    return view('blog.show', compact('article'));
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

articles migration file:

```
class CreateArticlesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('users')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('articles');
    }
}
```

Comment: Since this issue related to your Article table schema, could you update your question with information of your article table? That would be easier to debug

Comment: Strange... articles migration is missing and nowhere in recycle bin. Huh...? That's probably why I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is expecting an instance of Article. So, if you're returning a RedirectResponse from your closure, it won't work.

At the moment, I can only think of 2 ways of achieving what you want with route-model binding.

1. The first method is simpler. Just don't type-hint the Article. Instead, check if it's a RedirectResponse. If so, return it. If not, return the view. Something like this:

   ```
   public function show($article)
   {
       if ($article instanceof \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)
       {
           return $article;
       }
       return view('blog.show', compact('article'));
   }
   ```

You could also check if it's an instance of an Article just to be absolutely certain since you're no longer type-hinting.

2. The second method is overly complex in my opinion for a simple check. You would have to throw a custom exception, catch it from within `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`, and then redirect from there.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah, this is overly complicated for such simple logic. I hope route model binding doesn't hold me back like this in the future, just wanted to keep things a bit cleaner in my controllers. If it does I'll just start writing the stuff in controllers from now on. Thanks!